# jquery prevent box to close after submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After setting up a simple box dialog form I would like to keep the box open after submitting the form, but the box keeps closing.

After a little search into the jquery docs I came with `preventDefault` method on the event. I added that to the code, but the box keeping closing.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#toggle').click(function(e) {
        $('#box').toggleClass('max');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
  $('#close').click(function(e) {
      /*  $('#box').remove();*/
    });
});
```

It did not work, I've tried the  **stopPropagation()** and that did not worked either.

someone can spare a hint, please?

the html:

```
<div id="box" class="min">

    <span id ="toggle" class="fa fa-window-restore">
        <b>Open Dialog</b>
    </span>

    <form action="/conversations/3/reply" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
        <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="VgKXI1p4MumSlvZF51pbXYKMMRLFKs0Us4NUB2+O7VZalzk++QDNQ5SsQMzvt4HlgUnlMa3ux54IDc3R/tGZhA==" />
        <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Type something..." required="required"></textarea>
        <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn_green">Send Message</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: I think submit button reload the page...

Comment: if you submit the form, the page will be automatically refreshed, so you should submit the form via `ajax` call. so you can keep the form open and you can submit the form.

Comment: @AnfathHifans yes i know, but in this case i can't use ajax. anyway thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `preventDefault()` on the *form*'s `submit` event in order to prevent the page from being replaced by the form submission.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => e.preventDefault());
```